# slideToggle: two different easings

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, easing

I use slideToggle to include a notification bar that pushes down my header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#test').click(function() {
          $('#preheader').slideToggle('slow', 'easeOutBounce');
     });
});
```

Now I want to use two different easings. If it opens, I want it to open/push down linear. When it closes I want it to bounce.

How can I achieve the same effect of slideToggle but only with two different easings for each open/close event?

Comment: add an if statement that checks to see if the container you are toggling is visible. If it is then use one method. If not, use the other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag to know when the element is open or closed, and set the animation and easing based on that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#test').on('click', function() {
          var open   = $(this).data('open'),
              easing = open ? 'easeOutBounce' : 'easeInBounce';

          $('#preheader')[open ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']('slow', easing);

          $(this).data('open', !open);
     });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NAL5K/1/)

Comment: Two questions: instead of slideUp and slideDown can I somehow use animate? Also I want to "pre-render" this div and give it a top offset of minus its height.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#test').click(function() {
          $('#preheader').slideToggle('slow', ($('#preheader').is(':visible') ? 'easeOutBounce' : 'slideDown'));
     });
});
```